# Registered sidebar area is not shown from plugin.

Tags: plugins, widgets, options

I am trying to list all registered sidebar. But while I put the code inside plugin it does not work but if I put it inside theme it works.

```
function chup_list_sidebar(){
  $sidebar_options = array();
  $sidebars = $GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars'];

  foreach ( $sidebars as $sidebar ){
      $sidebar_options[] = array(
        'name'  => $sidebar['name'],
        'value' => $sidebar['id']
     );
   }
  return $sidebar_options;
}
```

If I put inside theme function.php the var dump

> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(7) "Sidebar" ["value"]=> string(9) "sidebar-1" } }

Now placing inside my plugin

> array(0) { }

I think I am missing plugable functions or I am loading function before loading `$GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars']` global. So what's the catch?

Comment: Where are you using `chup_list_sidebar()`? Sidebars are registered on the `widgets_init` hook, which itself is in a function hooked to `init` at priority 1. If you call any earlier than that it won't be populated. Plugins are loaded prior to `init` (so are themes, but templates are loaded after), so you can only use it in a function hooked somewhere after init.

Comment: That's what I am thinking , it's not populated. I am using that chunk of code inside my plugin teritory. Does if I load after init hook ,shall it work?

Comment: Yeah it should. When I say where are you using it, I mean what hook are you in when you use it?

Comment: Currently no hook, just plain function to return array, init hook does not work.

Comment: I think I have to go for custom db query

Comment: Not going to work. Sidebars aren’t stored in the database. They’re registered in code on every load. And you can define the function outside a hook, but it would work if you *use* it in a hook. If you’re writing a WordPress plugin then you’d want to use that function to do something in a hook presumably? So what are you trying to do with the function.

Comment: You are wrong. Registered sidebar is stored in wp_options table. I just wanted to show which sidebar user wants to show .

Comment: No mate, they're not. *Widgets* are stored in `sidebars_widgets`, and they are organised by sidebar ID, but none of the other information about the sidebars is in there, such as the name. That db record will also include inactive and orphaned widgets.